Solve the congruence $15^x \equiv 10 \pmod {31}$
Honestly, I don't think that $\exists x$. I made a python script to find some solutions, but at least up to $100000$ I don't found any one. Is there any way to prove that?

You can use brute force and try all the principal values into the congruence equation. There are 31 values, there are not so many. It has no (integer) solutions.

Try again, make a script that prints out, one pair per line, $x$ and $15^x \pmod{31} $ Here's the thing:  it is guaranteed that $15^{30} \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$  so it all cycles. Just print out for $1 \leq x \leq 31$  and check for repetition.

There are no solutions  Simplifying
the congruence eventually it becomes:
,$1^x \equiv 11 \ (\text{mod} \ 31)$ which has no solutions

Yes, Wolfram also says no integer solutions exist.

@CircuitSage how did you simplify to $1^x \equiv 11 \pmod {31}$?

Raising both sides to power $,5,$ yields $,(-1)^x\equiv 25\pmod{!31},,$ contradiction. $\ \ $

Diego, could  you please make the short program I described and find out the numbers $n$  for which there is a solution  to $15^x \equiv n \pmod{31}. $   There are exactly ten such numbers from $1$   to $30$

@WillJagy https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/23cgc/ Certainly, there are multiple values of $x$ for various values of $n$. But for $n=10$, it apparently does not exist a valid $x$.

Diego, I don't know how to get that to execute. Could you please type in the list of ten numbers, in a comment below or in the question body?

It's a little easier to see that @BillDubuque's comment will work nicely if we write $15\equiv -2^{-1}\pmod{31}$ and $10\equiv-3^{-1}\pmod{31}$; then the desired congruence becomes $(-2)^x \equiv -3\pmod{31}$, and raising to the $5$th power is more natural because $2^5=32\equiv1\pmod{31}$.

Greg Indeed. In fact I too used $,15\equiv -1/\color{#0af}2\pmod{!\color{#0af}2^{\large\color{#c00}5}!-1},$ to choose the power $:!\color{#c00}5:!$ to raise to above. $\ \ $

For non-negative integer $x$, we have $15^{x+10}-15^x=15^x\cdot18601625504\cdot 31$, hence
$15^{x+10}=15^x\mod 31$. As a result, it's enough to check $15^x\mod 31$ only for $x=0,1,\dots,9$. The remainders are
$$
1 ,  15 ,  8 ,  27 ,  2 ,  30 ,  16 ,  23 ,  4 ,  29
$$
none of which equals $10$, so there's no solution.

You could have stopped as soon as you have found a duplicate so at the 10th iteration because $15^{10}\equiv 15^0\pmod{31}$ (value is $1$...)

what was the need to put that large 6185518039770454408661011726625504 factor in... just noting $\phi(31) = 30$, was sufficient....

Simpler: we can stop at $15^{\large\color{darkorange}5}\equiv -1$ since the remaining powers will be negations of the prior: $1,\color{#0af}{15},\color{#c00}{8},\color{#0a0}{-4},2,-1,\color{#0af}{-15},\color{#c00}{-8},\color{#0a0}4,-2,1.,$ So it suffices to check that $\pm 10,$ is not among the first $,\color{darkorange}5,$ powers, i.e. $,\pm10\not\equiv 2^n,, n<\color{darkorange}5.,$ Even simpler: raise both sides of the congruence  to power $,\color{darkorange}5,,$ cf. my earlier comment on the question. $\ \ $
